# Generating a list of hour:minute in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Im trying to generate a numpy array of minutes from 9:30 to 16:00. (6.5 hours*60 minutes=390 elements)

Is there something similar to:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.date_range("09:30", "16:00", freq="1min")
```

Of course after it to convert to numpy is easy...

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
a = pd.date_range("09:30", "16:00", freq="1min").strftime('%H:%M')
print (a[:10])
['09:30' '09:31' '09:32' '09:33' '09:34' '09:35' '09:36' '09:37' '09:38'
 '09:39']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
t = np.arange(datetime.datetime(2018,3,12,9,30), datetime.datetime(2018,3,12,16,0), datetime.timedelta(hours=1)).astype(datetime.datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that high-level for date/time management in `numpy`, but it is not too difficult to have your own with the help of the `datetime` standard module.
One way of doing this would be:

```
import datetime

def date_range(
        begin_time,
        end_time,
        step_time,
        in_date_fmt='%H:%M',
        out_date_fmt=None,
        upper_bound=False):
    if out_date_fmt is None:
        out_date_fmt = in_date_fmt 

    begin_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(begin_time, in_date_fmt)
    end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, in_date_fmt)

    delta_time = (end_time - begin_time)
    origin_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('0', '%S')
    step_time = (
        datetime.datetime.strptime(step_time, in_date_fmt) - origin_time)

    if upper_bound:
        upper_bound = step_time.seconds

    for i in range(0, delta_time.seconds + upper_bound, step_time.seconds):
       yield (
           begin_time + 
           datetime.timedelta(seconds=i)).strftime(out_date_fmt)
```

Which can be used this way:

```
my_date_range = np.array(list(date_range('09:30', '16:00', '00:01')))
```

The docstring is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Of course, if you can use `pandas` you should really use it and not invent **Yet Another Wheel™**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.datetime64`. But it will insist on being given a year-month-day, as well.

```
r = np.arange('0000-01-01T09:30', '0000-01-01T16:00', dtype='M8')
r
# array(['0000-01-01T09:30', '0000-01-01T09:31', '0000-01-01T09:32',
#        '0000-01-01T09:33', '0000-01-01T09:34', '0000-01-01T09:35',
#         ...
#        '0000-01-01T15:54', '0000-01-01T15:55', '0000-01-01T15:56',
#        '0000-01-01T15:57', '0000-01-01T15:58', '0000-01-01T15:59'],
#       dtype='datetime64[m]')
```

You could get rid of the date by subtracting it but the resulting `np.timedelta64` does display as minutes.

```
d = r - r[0].astype('M8[D]')
d
# array([570, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582,
#        583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595,
#        ...
#        934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939, 940, 941, 942, 943, 944, 945, 946,
#        947, 948, 949, 950, 951, 952, 953, 954, 955, 956, 957, 958, 959],
#       dtype='timedelta64[m]')
```

Hours can be extracted, though:

```
>> d.astype('m8[h]')
# array([ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,
#         9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
#         ...

#        15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15,
#        15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15],
#       dtype='timedelta64[h]')
```